# Powershell different actions on parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to specify 3 parameters to a command line which do different things

1)

```
command -fwList
```

Will run a specific function (get-content) that will return a list of firewalls, so without needing any parameters this should be run

2)

Then these parameters are mandatory and required together

```
command -fwName <firewallName> -fwCommand <command>
```

Here's what I have so far but how to I make them dependent on each other?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string]$fwList,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$fwName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
[string]$fwCommand
)
```

Comment: What exactly they need to depend on? Can you just make them all Mandatory? You probably want to use ParameterSet names for parameters combos.

Comment: -fwName and -fwCommand depend on each other and are both required, so they will be used to pass the variable to an application which requires the firewall name and the command to run on the firewall. 

-fwList should be able to be run alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AgentK was close but there are a couple corrections needed.

First, the requirement for the `fwList` parameter is that it be a [switch parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.switchparameter%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than a string. Then within your code, you can treat `$fwList` as if it were a Boolean (at least most of the time; there are some nuances not relevant here).

Second, the `Position` argument of the `Parameter` attribute restarts with 0 on *each* parameter set; you do not want to start a parameter set with the first parameter at position 1.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='ListFirewalls', Position=0)]
   [switch]$fwList,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='ProcessFirewalls', Position=0)]
   [string]$fwName,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='ProcessFirewalls', Position=1)]
   [string]$fwCommand
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ParameterSetName='MyParamSetName1')]
[string]$fwList,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='MyParamSetName2',Position=1)]
[string]$fwName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='MyParamSetName2',Position=2)]
[string]$fwCommand
)
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I get -fwList to run something without requiring a variable? something like $fwList = $allFirewallIps

Comment: @user1776732 you could place default value to function parameter like this: [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ParameterSetName='MyParamSetName1')]
[string]$fwList='default_value'

Comment: and then what should I use as the default_value and how do I call it? I've also tried different options with $null